# Tomcat on Mac OS Yosemite (for iteraplan)

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, tomcat

for those who are familiar with the web application iteraplan, I really need help. I've been having trouble getting iteraplan to work on my Mac because some factors or requirements can't be fulfilled.

For this reason I needed to install Tomcat since it's a web application but I'm a newbie to it. Tomcat doesn't work even though I installed it properly, moved it to the right folder and made sure that Eclipse recognizes it as a server. When I'm trying to open anything on Tomcat on my localhost I can't open further pages of Tomcat because I always receive the same error:"The requested resource is not available" When I'm trying to run the web application iteraplan through my terminal, the localhost doesn't open either and I get the same error. 
I already changed most of the server file (which seems necessary for getting the web application to work) but that doesn't help either. Is there anything I might gave forgotten? Maybe something I would have to launch or something?
I would be glad for any advice because I desperately need this to work for my thesis.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yash, have you made sure that your Tomcat installation is working properly? You should be able to access the manager app (usually under localhost:8080/manager/html) and see all running applications, regardless of whether you have iteraplan deployed on the server or not. Also, to run iteraplan, you need a database (details can be found in the iteraplan installation guide: http://www.iteraplan.de/wiki/display/iteraplan34/Installation+Guide). Finally, if you just want to run the application, without modifying the code, it would be simpler to download one of the bundles available in sourceforge (http://sourceforge.net/projects/iteraplan/files/iteraplan Community Edition/). They have a Tomcat server and a database included.